# Are there known cases of an airline pilot's becoming incapacitated, while in command of the aircraft, during a critical flight phase?

Tags: airliner, aviation-history, pilot-incapacitation

Are there any reported cases in which the Pilot Flying of an airliner has become incapacitated during a critical phase of flight, so that the Pilot Monitoring has had to intervene to prevent a disaster?

By *critical phases of flight*, I mean during takeoff, approach, or landing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples from two studies that have a lot more detail and background information on pilot incapacitation in general.

From [an ATSB study](https://www.atsb.gov.au/media/5768970/ar-2015-096-final.pdf):

> After a normal touchdown, the first officer became unconscious at the
>   flight controls and the aircraft began to veer to the right of the
>   centreline. The captain took control of the aircraft to return to the
>   centreline and completed the landing

From [an FAA study](https://www.faa.gov/data_research/research/med_humanfacs/oamtechreports/2000s/media/0416.pdf):

> A 45-year-old B-737 first officer experiencing an alcohol withdrawal
>   seizure suddenly screamed, extended his arms up rigidly, pushed full
>   right rudder, and slumped over the yoke during an approach. The
>   aircraft descended to 1,000 feet above ground level in an
>   uncoordinated turn to 25 degrees angle of bank before flight
>   attendants could pull the first officer off the controls, allowing the
>   captain to recover the airplane

Comment: Wait, so this incident happened because the FO wasn't drunk *enough*?